# Is there a way to make ejtserver talk http?

Tags: install4j

We need to set up an ejtserver instance inside an OpenShift cloud and expose it to an external network.
I have been told that a binary protocol is a big no-no in that situation, as it requires an extra, manually-set-up egress route (lots of extra work by external team), and takes up a limited resource (port number - ports numbers for binary egress routes need to be unique).

No such limitations exist for HTTP(S) traffic because the routers know enough about the protocol to differentiate connections through host name, which is an unlimited resource.
So I hope I can make the connection from install4j-maven-plugin to the ejtserver instance through HTTP(S); is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.13.1, this is not possible, please contact ***support@ej-technologies.com*** for alternative arrangements with build-only license keys.